# Is scipy.misc.imread safe/efficient to run from multiple threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, scipy, multiprocessing, python-imaging-library

I have set up a producer/consumer model using python Queues. In one producer I'm reading images using `scipy.misc.imread`.

Reading images in one thread is not fast enough, it takes ~0.2s per image to read. About 20MB/sec reading from an SSD.

I tried adding another identical thread using python's `threading` module. However the time spent in `scipy.misc.imread` increased by approximately double, causing the 2 threads to read images approximately as fast as the 1 did.

I'm sure my SSD can handle 40MB/sec throughput, even with random reads. A `dd` write test shows 800MB+/sec write speeds.

I am left wondering if `scipy.misc.imread` runs as a critical region among threads? Would I expect `multiprocessing` to avoid the problem?

Comment: `scipy.misc.imread` is just a thin wrapper around PIL. How large are the images? What format are they in (in particular, are they compressed)?

Comment: Also, which version of PIL do you have installed? Is it the Pillow fork, or the original PIL library? Up until [this commit](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/1224), Pillow/PIL did not release the GIL during image decoding. I don't have the source to hand, but I would guess that the original PIL also doesn't release the GIL.

Comment: I'm using Anaconda, so whatever versions come with that. I have run the first tests with multiprocessing and it appears to not have the same issue, I have to run a few more tests to make sure my eyes don't deceive me. Images are 2MB each, I need to read and queue at a rate of 20 images/sec.

Comment: That's consistent with having an older version of PIL that doesn't release the GIL during decoding. You could check the version using `import PIL; print(PIL.PILLOW_VERSION)` (this won't exist if you're not using the Pillow fork of PIL). The first Pillow release that includes the change I mentioned above is v2.9.0. If this explanation is correct then you could either install a more recent version of Pillow, or use `multiprocessing` instead of `threading` to circumvent the GIL, as you're already doing.

Comment: @ali_m that was it, multiprocessing works, multithreading doesn't. If you'd post that as an answer I'll call it done.

Comment: Sure, but I don't think I've really answered your original question yet! It would probably be useful for future readers if you could you say which version of PIL/Pillow you're using. Did you ever test whether upgrading it resulted in any performance improvements when using `threading` instead of `multiprocessing`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scipy.misc.imread` is safe from multiple threads, but each call locks the global interpreter, so performance won't benefit from multithreading.

It works well from multiprocessing, no unexpected issues.